# jQuery $.Deferred with window.top.postMessage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, deferred, postmessage

I cannot figure out how to properly work with $.Deferred.

I have something very similar to

```
window.top.postMessage(mystring, myorigin);
```

That works just fine. I do not need help sending/receiving `postMessage`

I want to listen for when the message has been sent. It appears to be possible with $.Deferred. I am using jQuery, so jQuery answers are acceptable, though I will also take non-jQuery answers.

It appears to be used in [please.js](https://github.com/wingify/please.js/blob/master/src/please.js) and there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892864/why-is-my-deferred-object-set-to-resolved-instead-of-pending-when-calling-a-func), but I'm unable to extrapolate how they're functioning by browsing their code.

Perhaps I am going about this wrong, postMessage can sometimes fail to send.

Thanks

Comment: You're just triggering an event, there is no fail or succeed, and it's synchronous so there's no need for a callback or waiting.

Comment: @KevinB `postMessage` is asynchronous.

Comment: What object do you want to be listening for `postMessage` sending?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain anymore what I'm looking for. I wanted a "success/fail" callback similar to $.ajax. Perhaps I'm going about this wrong?

Comment: I mean, sure, but there's no callback for it, from the point of view of the page posting the message, there's nothing to wait for, so is it really asynchronous? it will always succeed, regardless if anything is listening for the event on the top page.

Comment: @KevinB: It is on the receiving page :-)

Comment: It's as asynchronous as a custom event is.

Comment: @RandyHall What would you expect a "fail" to be caused by in this case?

Comment: Trying to postMessage to something that doesn't exist, or with improper arguments.

Comment: @RocketHazmat No I'm referring to the sending page. I have no problem receiving the message I sent, as per the original question.

Comment: It looks as though the answer is indeed that there is no success/fail for postMessage, though it is technically asynchronous. It does not return anything at all (undefined). Try... catch is probably the right direction for errors with the function.

$.Deferred seemed like such an elegant solution. Oh well, it happens.

Comment: Well, you could create a system revolving around $.Deferred, it would require code on both sides. First, the client side (the side sending the request) will need to initiate a request with a specific id in it's data string, then the receiver page will need to receive the message, perform it's action, then send another message back to the client with the response and the same id. You can use the response to then decide to either resolve or reject the deferred. You'd be basically re-creating $.ajax in a way, it may even be worth making it an ajax transport with timeout functionality.

Comment: That is a good way to handle it I think. I'll work on it, but I'm still light on understanding with how $.Deferred is used.

Comment: @KevinB if you want to post a short example of $.Deferred handler I'll accept that as the answer, get you some points. If not, I'll just post my version when I'm finished.

Comment: I would like to see your version, i don't have one written yet as i haven't had a need for this kind of communication.

Answer (score -2):

otherWindow can listen for dispatched messages by executing the following JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

[Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Comment: I have no problem receiving the message I sent, as per the original question.